# How to Make my Footer Push with Content?

Tags: html, css, footer

Ok, so I have this footer on my page I'm designing, but I've encountered a problem; the footer sticks to the bottom of the page, but content can go past it... this is what I mean - http://i46.tinypic.com/2zted15.png.

Here is my the CSS/HTML code for my footer: http://pastebin.com/ZKCuBjhn

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Edit:
Here is the code for the whole page - 
HTML code: pastebin.com/RAj11cPP ---
CSS code: pastebin.com/0kMgb1R2

Note: The ridiculous amount of 
 tags in the code was to demonstrate my problem.

Comment: We need more code for the rest of the page.

Comment: Added links to full code in original post.

Comment: Do you needed absolutely positioned or it just have to flow when the middle pushes it downward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `clear: both;` to your footer style. It would be nice to see the code of the rest of the page howerver.

**Real Answer:**
After looking at your code, it seems like this is more what you want: http://pastebin.com/Letx9hPA

I changed you footer's position to fixed so that it stayed on the bottom of the page. If that isn't what you want then remove position all together so that it is free to be pushed down.

Also I wrapped your content in a content div so that I could add the spacer needed at the bottom to make it all visible. Spacer added by setting `padding-bottom: 100px` which is the height of your footer.

Comment: No problem, here is the HTML code: http://pastebin.com/RAj11cPP and the CSS code: http://pastebin.com/0kMgb1R2   Note: The ridiculous amount of <br> tags was to demonstrate my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're using position: absolute for the div, so you're removing it from th normal flow of the page, afterwards, the upper content will pass through.

In the case your previous html is a div or something like that enclosing the whole superior piece, then use the div, DON'T "position absolute" it, use width: 100% and margin: 0 auto; The problem is not your footer, is the code that comes before the footer.

In case it's a div, you HAVE TO give some height but using min-height, so when the content inside it overflows, the div behaves nicely and push your footer downward. If you use height, then the div will adopt that height and your overflowing insides will leak off.

Here's a simple code:

```
body {
        background-color: #d6d6d6;
    }

    .header {
        background-color: #006F8D;
        color: #fff;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 600px;
        height: 100px;
    }

    .center {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #454545;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 600px;
        min-height: 100px;
    }

    .footer {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #454545;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 600px;
        height: 50px;
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
```

That's for the CSS, now for the HTML:

```
<div class="header">menu 1 - menu2 - menu3</div>
    <div class="center">Middle<br />
    Middle<br />
    Middle<br />
    Middle<br />
    Middle<br /><br />
    v
    v
    Middle<br /><br />Middle<br /><br />Middle<br /><br />v
    v<br />v
    Middle<br /><br />v
    v<br />Middle<br />
    v
    v
    v
    v
    v
    v
    vMiddle<br />Middle<br />Middle<br />Middle<br />
    <br />Middle<br />Middle<br />Middle<br />Middle<br />Middle<br />Middle<br />Middle<br />
</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

If you need to absolutely position your footer then the answer is another one. Clarify me that and I'll answer the other question.

EDIT: Your code with mine (didn't used your css, and GOD, DON'T use that deprecated TAGS!!!! font, center, etc.)

```
   <style type="text/css">
           .header {
        background-color: #006F8D;
        color: #fff;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 600px;
        height: 100px;
    }

    .center {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #454545;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 600px;
        min-height: 100px;
    }

    .footer {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #454545;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 600px;
        height: 50px;
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
</style>
</head>
<title>Website Homepage</title>
<body>

<!--====================Begin Navigation Bar========================-->
<div class="header" id="navigation">
<div style="float:left;">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a>
    <a href="login.html">Login</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
 </div>
<!--====================End Navigation Bar==========================-->

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<!--====================Begin Content Area======================-->
<div class="center" style="padding:10">
See my problem?
</div>
<!--====================End Content Area========================-->

    <!--====================Begin Footer========================-->

<div class='footer'>
<div style="padding-top:20px;">

                Website. All Rights Reserved.

<form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get" onSubmit="Gsitesearch(this)">
<input name="q" type="hidden" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Search our site..." name="qfont" /> <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
</div>
</div>

    <!--====================End Footer==========================-->

</body>
</html>
```